# Distinct Elements From a number

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a system in which we have to create an array and store distinct numbers that can be obtained from an integer.  Give Input:-

```
12
```

and the array of distinct numbers that can be generated from this number is:-

```
x={1,2,12}
```

But there is a catch that the distinct numbers cannot contain any leading zeros. I can delete a digit of the given number such that resulting number doesn't have any leading zeros.
Given Input

```
102
```

Now, the array formed is
`x={0,1,2,10,12}`

I am not able to solve the problem with leading zeros. Can anyone help me with the problem?

Comment: It would help if you could show us how you are generating the permutations now. There are many ways to approach this, and it's hard to provide a meaningful answer without knowing how you're approaching it.

Comment: Looks like you are playing with digit characters.  IMHO, read the number as a string, then treat the string as an array to access the digits and print them in different *combinations* or *permutations*.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem via substring. I computed the substring through 2 loops and if that string's first index value is zero, I didn't add it into my output array.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    
    vector<int> output;
    

    string snum = to_string(num); //converting my input number into a string
    
    //computing substring
    for (int i = 0; i < snum.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < snum.length(); j++) {
            //substring method
            string temp = snum.substr(i, j);

            //if the first index is zero I continue my loop (leading zero)
            if (temp[0] == '0')
                continue;
            else
            { 
                //converting the string again into a number and add it to my output array
                stringstream str(temp);
                int n = 0;
                str >> n;
                
                output.push_back(n);
            }
        }
    }
    output.push_back(num);
    //cout << output[0] << endl;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < output.size(); i++)
        cout << output[i] << "\n";
}
```

There maybe other optimized way to solve this problem.